# how can set action button up and down ? like stock android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am working on the incoming calling layout. now I want to like this layout which is used to if action up and action down like this image.

[image]

Comment: The simplest way to do this to add Lottie Animations, you can customise duration of animation, color and a lot more very easily. Or you can check out this link if you want to do it yourself, https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view

Comment: exactly I want to click on the button and that to move up and down. in a specific area.